# Is this a legal move to allocated a non-constant array?

Tags: c++

I've created  this code to solve some online answers which worked, but I was wondering if it is Okay to allocate dynamic memory this way. The array size is defined continuously throughout the loop. Is it okay?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int sum=0;
    int x;
    int *ptr = new int[x];
    ptr[0]=1;
    ptr[1]=2;

    int max = 4000000;

    int i=2;

    while (ptr[i-2]<max)            
    {
        ptr[i]=ptr[i-1]+ptr[i-2];
        i++;
    }
    // now we use (i -1) as the last array fill b/c i is bigger than 4 000 000
    // sort with val % 2 == 0  !modulus!

    for (int j=0; j<(i-1); j++) {
        if (ptr[j]%2==0) {
            sum+=ptr[j];
        }
    }

    delete[] ptr;

    cout<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not okay, since `int x;` is uninitialized and may contain some garbage.
**EDIT.**
From comments to this post.
1) Use `std::vector<int>` instead of C-array.
2) If don't want use vector - add loop that count elements and then allocate memory for array and work with it.
3) Use static array of some big size if first and second cases not approach.

Comment: So, how can I know the limit. What would cause heap overflow?

Comment: @Napster Use std::vector. Your code is incorrect at all. Also, you can use some static array. But vector is better.

Comment: @Napster because you should know count of elements, but in your code there is no calculating of elements... So, use vector, or add loop which count elements.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `int x` is uninitialized!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code:

1. `x` is not initialized to an initial value and so it may be some random value.
2. The `while` loop uses `ptr[i-2] < max` which implies (i) there needs to be at least two array elements, i.e., `x` must be set to a number no lower than 2 and (ii) `< max` is being comparing values in the array BUT there is no index check that i is between 2 and the number of array elements allocated with `new`. (When (ii) is coupled with `i++` in the `while` loop, it means that `i` might keep increasing well past the end of the allocated array.

You need to set `x` to a correct value and add checks to ensure you never access any array indices < 0 or any indices >= x every in your code you access the `ptr` array.

Consider using `std::vector` instead if manually managing the memory yourself.

**EDIT:** It looks like your code intend to compute the Fibonacci sequence and do a sum of even numbers. To fix up your code, this is what should be done:

1. Add `#include <vector>`.
2. Delete `int x;`
3. Delete `int *ptr = new int[x];` and replace it with `std::vector<int> v;`.
4. Replace `ptr[0]=1` with `v.push_back(1);`.
5. Replace `ptr[1]=2` with `v.push_back(2);`.
6. Replace the entire while loop.

Since it appears you are computing the Fibonacci sequence, you can loop using `int i=2` in the initialization part of a for loop while `v.back() < max` adding one each time, i.e., `++i`. For loops are excellent to this with. Within the loop, you can `v.push_back(v[i-1],v[i-2]);` to compute the next number and append it to the array.

As for `v.push_back(val)` this adds `val` to the end of the vector (i.e., the highest index) growing the vector (internally using dynamic memory) if required. `v.back()` is the last element of the vector, i.e., equivalent to `v[v.size()-1]` only if `v.empty()` is `false`.

1. Your comment mentions the for loop computing a larger value. However, your while loop does `i-2` --not `i-1` which is the second-to-last element --not the last element. Using `std::vector` it is easier to simply remove the last element if and only if it is >= 4000000. This can be handled using an if statement, i.e., `if (v.back() >= max)` then `v.pop_back();`.
2. Adjust your for loop (i.e., `i` should be `v.size()`).
3. Delete `delete[] ptr;`.

If you wanted to use dynamic memory allocation **directly** then the code would have to be written differently and would be more longer and complicated as you would have to be able to "resize" the array (which requires allocating more memory, copying the old contents into the new one, and then destroying the old one). Generally, however, you should use Standard Library containers and avoid directly managing memory. In this case `std::vector` is very well-suited to do this task using only a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, `x` is uninitialized when you try to use it as the size of array to allocate.

More importantly, however, at that point you don't really *know* how large of an array you'll need (I'm pretty sure it *could* be calculated, but we'll leave that for now).

Since you don't know the size up front, you pretty much need to allocate some space, produce some results, check the size, make more room of needed, and continue until you reach your target. Alternatively, you could do some really *trivial* math that would give a safe (if somewhat loose) estimate of the maximum size it could possibly. Since you're starting from 1, 2, and each cell will get larger than the previous, it's pretty safe to say that the maximum possible size needed will be no more than `max/2 = 2000000`.

Alternatively, you could just use `std::vector`, which is already built to handle situations like this.